# Trying to make buttons open different html files

Tags: javascript, html

So, making an app, where using buttons you navigate around, and it works fine going from the first page to the next, however, afterwards, the buttons on the subsequent page no longer function, even though their code is identical. Is there a way to keep the chain going?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTS-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
        <meta http-equiv="x-Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./temp.css">
        <title>I Have You</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="IHY" class="buttonA">IHY</button>
        <!-- <p id="info"></p> -->
    </body>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    <script src="./buttons.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is my main html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTS-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
        <meta http-equiv="x-Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./temp.css">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="friendButton" class="buttonB">Friends</button>
        <button id="settingsButton" class="buttonB">Settings</button>
    </body>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    <script src="./buttons.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is the page the button takes you to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTS-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
        <meta http-equiv="x-Content-Security-Policy"
            content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./temp.css">
        <title>Friends</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Friends :D</h2>
        <button id="homeButton" class="buttons">Back</button>
    </body>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    <script src="./buttons.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is where I want the "friends" button take me to

```js
document.getElementById("IHY").onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = src="./home.html";
}

document.getElementById("friendButton").onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = src="./friends.html"
};

document.getElementById("homeButton").onclick = () => {
    window.location.href = src="./home.html";
};
```

Heres my js for the buttons

I tried looking for anything online to fix this, but it isnt quite helping me, since it's all to do with websites, though im making an app.

Comment: You must use functions for this? Is it some kind of assignment or you think its best way to to it like this? Why don't you use `a` tag?You do not need functions for this... https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: You can also remove `src=` from your onclick functions, it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think you might be having is that each page is using the same script for the buttons.

Because each page uses the same script for the buttons, it's trying to load js for buttons that don't exist on certain pages.

Therefore you may be running into a script that is failing before it loads the event listeners for the existing buttons. It might be failing to register the DOM event for a button that does not exist on that page.

Without seeing any browser console errors it's a bit hard to tell at the moment, but can you try creating a different script for each page that loads the button event listeners for buttons that exist on those pages?

Comment: To clarify, `document.getElementById('thing').onclick = function() { ... }` will throw an error if there isn't an element with an ID of `thing` in the DOM. A safer way to do this would be to either get rid of the JS and change these to `<a href="./home.html">Home</a>`, or to change the JS to check if the element exists before setting the `onclick` value - `let homeButton = document.getElementById('home'); if (homeButton) { homeButtton.onclick = ...; }`